# How to validate SSN using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have most of my code done for it but for some reason, it is just submitting my form without doing anything. I'm trying to validate an SSN whether they enter it without or with dashes. As well as validating it I want to change the color of the words and background of input if it is invalid. I have my class names and IDs set up correctly and in my CSS I'm using things like `input.invalid`, `label.invalid` etc for color changes. here is what I have for my JS code. Any help would be great, thank you!

```
    window.onload = function () {

document.forms[0].onsubmit = validForm;

    }

 function validForm () {

var allTags = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("*");

for(vari = 0; i < allTags.length; i++) {
    
    validTag(allTags[i]);
    
}

return false;

function validTag(thisTag) {
    
    var outClass = "";
    
    var allClasses = thisTag.className.split(" ");
    
    for(var j = 0; j < allClasses.length; j++) {
        
        outClass += validBasedOnClass(allClasses[j]) + " ";
        
    }
    
    thisTag.className = outClass;
    
    if(outClass.indexOf("invalid") > -1) {
       
        invalidLabel(thisTag.parentNode);
        
        thisTag.focus();
        
        if(thisTag.nodeName == "INPUT") {
           
           thisTag.select();
           
        }
       
    }
    
    function validBasedOnClass(thisClass) {
        
        var classBack = "";
        
        switch(thisClass) {
                
            case "":
                
            case "invalid":
                break;
                
            case "Social":
                
                if(!validSocial(thisTag.value)) {
                   
                    document.getElementById("socialNum").className = ("invalid");
                    
                    document.getElementById("ssn").className = ("invalid");
                    
                   classBack = "invalid ";
                   
            }
                break;
                
            default:
                
                classBack += thisClass;
                
        }
        
        return classBack;
        
    }
    
    function validSocial(social) {
        
        var re = /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
        
        var socialArray = re.test(social);
        
        if(socialArray) {
            
            document.getElementById("socialNum").value = socialArray[1] + "-" + socialArray[2] + "-" + socialArray[3];
            
            return true;
           
        }
        
        return false;
        
    }
    
    function invalidLabel(parentTag) {
        
        if(parentTag.nodeName == "LABEL") {
           
            parentTag.className += "invalid";
           
           }
        
    }
    
}
```

}

here is my HTML code as requested

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

COP2831: Chapter 7 - Regular Expressions

## Regular Expressions - Kevin Taylor

Enter Social Security Number:

Comment: Take a look at [ask]. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [mcve]"

Comment: i stated the desired behavior. i need it to validate the ssn. as well as change the color of my text for the label and input. this isn't debugging help as clearly my code is not functioning. have i produced most of the code? yes. i need help figuring out why it isn't validating. which is an issue. not debugging. if it was a spelling or syntax error i would not be here.

Comment: 'debugging' is not 'a spelling or syntax error'. your question is still 'why doesn't this work'. 'validate ssn' is not a clear statement of 'desired behaviour'. Please do read the linked things and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: If you took the time to read the post it actually doesn't say "why doesn't this work" im simply asking for help on my code. If you don't want to help them move on please. As my post simply asks how do I validate a form with a ssn while using regular expressions. There's no other way to ask this question as I have said my code does not validate it, it submits it without checking whether it is a valid input option. I have a desired behavior in my post, again if you read it you might understand it. Thank you and good day to you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your sample is not complete and I do not really get why you do it this way I just give a simplified working sample of your SSN validation.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = validForm;
};
function validForm() {
    var ssnTag = document.getElementById("socialNum");
    var re = /^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/;
    var valid = re.test(ssnTag.value);
    if (valid) {
        ssnTag.style.borderColor = "green";
    } else {
        ssnTag.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    return false;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3swfxseo/)

Comment: Thank you! the only reason i was trying to do it that way is because, that is the way my college book shows how to do it. Seems like this book is making things way more complicated. Thank you for the help this is working. Is there anyway to change the input to where if i enter a ssn like 123456789 after i submit it will change it to 123-45-6789?

Comment: That's a bit harder to do. You could use a regex with groups `/^(\d{3})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{4})$/` collect the values from group $1, $2, $3, glue them together again, and update the textbox.

Comment: Thanks! I got it figured out finally, did exactly that with using the groups $1, $2, $3. Thank you!